# Limitless count for occurrences in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a piece of code designed to analyse multiple files in a directory and output various details upon request. I'm trying to figure out how to implement a histogram like system to display this data.

Currently my output looks like this..

```
Metric of interest? lines_of_code
lines_of_code        8
lines_of_code        23
```

When I'm trying to achieve this result..

```
Metric of interest? lines_of_code

Bin range    Count
0-9            1
20-29          1
```

How would I go about doing this? From what I've seen, most people feel as if importing `counter` from `collections` is the way to go.

This is what that segment of code looks like..

```
elif metric_choice == 'lines_of_code':
    for files in os.listdir("."):
        if files.endswith(".py"):
            file_open = open(files, "r")
            file_contents = file_open.readlines()
            print("{0:20} {1}".format("lines_of_code", (len(file_contents))))
```

Cheers!

Comment: What OS are you on?  It's probably easier just to call `wc --lines` if available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import glob
import collections

counter = collections.Counter()
for py_filename in glob.glob('*.py'):
    with open(py_filename) as f:
        linecount = sum(1 for line in f)
    counter[linecount//10] += 1

for i,n in sorted(counter.items()):
    print('{}-{}: {}'.format(i * 10, (i + 1) * 10 - 1, n))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Is it possible to group the first two values for alignment purposes like in my example? E.g. Something along the lines of `print('{{}-{}:<12}`.

Comment: Experiment with the syntax defined [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings). A simple example: `'{:2}-{:2}:{:5}'.format(1,10,3)`